# jQuery - find anchor by href value using a variable

Tags: jquery, href

I have a problem with selecting by href value assigned to a variable.

This code works as expected:
`$('a[href="/sites/example/page.aspx"]')`

However, if I assign the above url to a variable, it doesn't find the href. e.g.

`var myurl = "/sites/example/page.aspx"
$('a[href=myurl]')`

I tried entering the variable with or without quotes and a few different ideas, but can't get to it. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use concatenation sign `+` to concatenate the variable to the selector else the selector will be something like :

```
a[href=myurl]
```

Instead of :

```
a[href="/sites/example/page.aspx"]
```

```js
var myurl = "/sites/example/page.aspx";

console.log($('a[href="' + myurl + '"]').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="/sites/example/page.aspx">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the variable in the quotes. You should concat the variable like this.

$('a[href='+myurl+']')